# Odoo - Add menuitem to portal group

Tags: xml, security, odoo

I'm trying to add a menu to the portal group to be viewed only when I check in the portal group box but it didn't work, I don't know why.

```
    <menuitem id="sales_menu_sub_for_poral" name="Reporting"
              sequence="20" groups="base.group_portal"/>

    <menuitem id="sales_menu_no_sub_o" name="Sales"
              parent="sales_menu_sub_for_poral" sequence="30" groups="base.group_portal"/>

    <menuitem id="sales_menu_no_sub_o_go_po" name="Sales Analysis"
              parent="sales_menu_no_sub_o" sequence="40" action="sale.action_order_report_all" groups="base.group_portal"/>
```

Comment: Are you giving proper `access rights` for that model...??

Comment: i did not gave any access rights ,, just portal access right

Comment: Yup,, but for ex. your `sale.order` model has no access rights for portal user then it will be not visible for portal user....  You can refer **`portal_sale`** module as an example. In that module under the **security** folder, Some models has an access rights for portal. So, it will be access by portal users.......   :) ;)

Comment: ty i got it :) that was easy

Comment: So, for your case i think...  you give the access rights for the model that is defined in your action `sale.action_order_report_all` and that model is **`sale.report`**  , just defined the access-rights for this model... and you will go fineeeeee.......   :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Access rights to the module and Voila it's working like Charm